Актуальный метод авторизации во Вконтакте
господа. Возникла необходимость получать данные из Вконтакте путём запросов к страницам парсинга HTML. Например делается запрос к профилю пользователя и вся информация о нём хранится в HTML.
Вконтакте крайне требователен к кукки, хедерам и подобным вещам, и просто так ничего не отдаст.
Пытался сделать через библиотеку на python "vk_api" (там есть возможность авторизоваться и пользоваться авторизованной сессией), однако библиотека давно не обновлялась в этом плане и даже в ней самой авторизация проходит через раз.
Есть ли какая-то актуальная информация как успешно проходить авторизацию и спокойно получать данные путём прямых запросов?
Прошу не предлагать официальное API, т.к задача стоит именно в парсинге HTML. Наверное вопрос бы легко решил Selenium, однако есть требования по скорости работы.
Заранее спасибо.
